# update object recursively with es6

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6

I have many objects with children inside a dataTree and I want to update the toggle value to true recursively with an es6 syntax and get back the updated dataTree

the object looks like this

```
{
    name: "Misc", 
    toggled: true,
    children: [{
        name: "Apple",
        toggled:false
        children: [{
            name: "banana",
            toggled:false
        }]
    }]
}
```

etc...

Any idea, Thanks

Comment: It's polite to show some effort and research before you ask someone else to do the work for you... try googling recursively iterating through an object javascript

Comment: @MatthewBrent I didn't find anything which is es6 and updates the previous data and not extracts it. Otherwise, I won't post.

Comment: es6 is more or less just going to be syntax differences. Dont learn two things at once - write it in es5 - i'd recommend using array.prototype.map to iterate through your array of objects to get started. dont edit the object in place but generate a new one and return that from your function

Comment: how about converting it to string then replace all toggled:true to toggled:false and then convert string back to json?

Comment: @sumit part of me wants think that's a horrible idea but another part of me thinks that's pretty cool

Answer (score 1):

Make a module for your type of `{ name, toggled, children }` - here we call ours `Node`

```
const Node =
  { make : (name = "", toggled = false, children = []) =>
      ({ name, toggled, children })

  , toggle : (node) =>
      Node.make (node.name, !node.toggled, node.children)

  , toggleAll : (node) =>
      Node.make (node.name, !node.toggled, node.children.map (Node.toggleAll))
  }
```

Note that `toggle` and `toggleAll` do not mutate the original input - instead, a new Node is always created

```
const n =
  Node.make ("foo", true)

console.log (n, Node.toggle (n), n)
// { name: 'foo', toggled: true, children: [] }
// { name: 'foo', toggled: false, children: [] }
// { name: 'foo', toggled: true, children: [] }
```

We can use this directly on your `data` to toggle all `toggled` fields

```
const data = 
  { name : "Misc"
  , toggled : true
  , children :
    [ { name : "Apple"
      , toggled : false
      , children :
        [ { name : "banana"
          , toggled : false
          , children : []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

console.log (Node.toggleAll (data))

// { name : "Misc"
// , toggled : false              <--- toggled
// , children :
//   [ { name : "Apple"
//     , toggled : true           <--- toggled
//     , children :
//       [ { name : "banana"
//         , toggled : true       <--- toggled
//         , children : []
//         }
//       ]
//     }
//   ]
// }
```

But instead of writing your data with object literal syntax, you should use your module instead

```
const data =
  Node.make ( "Misc"
            , true
            , [ Node.make ( "Apple"
                          , false
                          , [ Node.make ("banana", false) ]
                          )
              ]
            )

console.log (Node.toggleAll (data))
// same output
```

> I want to update the toggle value to true recursively ...

If you want to set all `toggled` to a specific value, you could write a specific function for it

```
const Node =
  { ...
  , toggleAllOn : (node) =>
      Node.make (node.name, true, node.children.map (Node.toggleAllOn))
  }
```

Or, instead of making lots of specific functions, we could make our original `Node.toggle` and `Node.toggleAll` more flexible using a parameter

```
const TOGGLE =
  Symbol ()

const Node =
  { make : (name = "", toggled = false, children = []) =>
      ({ name, toggled, children })

  , toggle : (node, value = TOGGLE) =>
      Node.make ( node.name
                , value === TOGGLE ? !node.toggled : Boolean (value)
                , node.children
                )

  , toggleAll : (node, value = TOGGLE) =>
      Node.make ( node.name
                , value === TOGGLE ? !node.toggled : Boolean (value)
                , node.children.map (n => Node.toggleAll (n, value))
                )
  }
```

Now we can toggle a node `n` using `Node.toggle (n)` *or* set a specific toggle state using `Node.toggle (n, true)` or `Node.toggle (n, false)`

```
const n =
  Node.make ("foo", true)

console.log (n, Node.toggle (n, true), Node.toggle (n), n)
// { name: 'foo', toggled: true, children: [] }     <--- original
// { name: 'foo', toggled: true, children: [] }     <--- already true; no change
// { name: 'foo', toggled: false, children: [] }    <--- toggled
// { name: 'foo', toggled: true, children: [] }     <--- immutable
```

Of course it works for `Node.toggleAll (n, true)` too

```
const allTrue =
  Node.toggleAll (data, true)

console.log (allTrue)
// { name : "Misc"
// , toggled : true              <--- same value
// , children :
//   [ { name : "Apple"
//     , toggled : true          <--- set to true
//     , children :
//       [ { name : "banana"
//         , toggled : true      <--- set to true
//         , children : []
//         }
//       ]
//     }
//   ]
// }
```

Program demonstration

```js
const TOGGLE =
  Symbol ()

const Node =
  { make : (name = "", toggled = false, children = []) =>
      ({ name, toggled, children })

  , toggle : (node, value = TOGGLE) =>
      Node.make ( node.name
                , value === TOGGLE ? !node.toggled : value
                , node.children
                )

  , toggleAll : (node, value = TOGGLE) =>
      Node.make ( node.name
                , value === TOGGLE ? !node.toggled : value
                , node.children.map (n => Node.toggleAll (n, value))
                )
  }
      
const data =
  Node.make ( "Misc"
            , true
            , [ Node.make ( "Apple"
                          , false
                          , [ Node.make ("banana", false) ]
                          )
              ]
            )

// display original
console.log ('original', data)

// only toggle this node
console.log ('toggle', Node.toggle (data))

// toggle this node and all children
console.log ('toggleAll', Node.toggleAll (data))

// set this node and all children to true
console.log ('toggleAll true', Node.toggleAll (data, true))

// check original data is not mutated (OK!)
console.log ('original', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you want, but I tried.

```
var obj = {
    name: "Misc", 
    toggled: true,
    children: [{
        name: "Apple",
        toggled:false,
        children: [{
            name: "banana",
            toggled:false
        }]
    }]
};

var toggleToTrue = function(obj){

    if (!obj) { return false; }
    obj.toggled = true;

    if (!obj.children) { return false; }    
    var childs = obj.children;    
    for (var i in childs){
        toggleToTrue(childs[i]);
    }

};

toggleToTrue(obj);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I'd recommend against editing the object in place but creating a new one as you recurse through the object and returning that.

Comment: Yes you true. I just understand that he want to update the current item.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following for a recursive solution that doesn't mutate the original object, doesn't add properties to objects that didn't have those properties (adding `toggled` if object doesn't have it) and can be configured by caller to change some behavior:

```js
var obj = {
  name: "Misc", 
  toggled: true,
  children: [{
      name: "Apple",
      toggled:false,
      children: [{
          name: "banana",
          toggled:false
      }]
  }]
};

const changeProp = (shouldSet,set,doRecursive,rec) => calcValue => (obj) => {
  const toggle = o => {
    if (shouldSet(o)) {
      return set({ ...o },calcValue(o));
    }
    return o;
  };
  return (!doRecursive(obj))
    ? toggle(obj)
    : rec(toggle(obj),changeProp(shouldSet,set,doRecursive,rec)(calcValue))
};

const hasChild = o=>(o.hasOwnProperty("children") && Array.isArray(o.children));
const setRecursive = (o,rec)=>({ 
  ...o,
  children:o.children.map(rec)
});

//set toggled to true
console.log(
  changeProp(
    o=>(typeof o.toggled === "boolean"),//should set function
    (o,value)=>{o.toggled=value;return o; },//set function
    hasChild,//do recursive?
    setRecursive//recursively set
  )(()=>true)//calculate value based on object (value is always true)
  (obj)
);
//upper case name
console.log(
  changeProp(
    o=>(typeof o.name === "string"),//should set function
    (o,value)=>{o.name=value;return o; },//set function
    hasChild,//do recursive?
    setRecursive//recursively set
  )((o)=>o.name.toUpperCase())//calculate value based on object (name to uppercase)
  (obj)
);
```

Comment: a 6-ary, partially curried function should be an indication that there's probably a better way ...